# How to resolve circular imports errors in Python3 when using Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-import

I'd like to split the files of Python code in a similar way to Java OOP

```
class.py
class2.py
...
```

this is my project GitHub : https://github.com/fds-napolitain/poa-pacman/tree/arch

I've read the problem is that using my example, app.py would need partie.py loaded, and so on, but it seems very difficult/confusing with Tkinter since all files need references.

How do I resolve the circular imports ?

Comment: Why does partie.py need to import app? It doesn't use anything from app.

Comment: It uses app attributes window, background for example

Comment: Then you need to pass a reference to the instance of App to Partie when you initialise it. I'm not sure why you are using a static method for each of your classes. No other tkinter app I've ever seen does that. Use the standard `__init__` method when initialising a class rather than your `initialize` static methods

Comment: I’ll try it but I though static classes made more sense as both App and Partie can have just one instance!

Comment: That might be a common Java thing but it isn't for Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved by removing circular import (no really ^^) by adding references to canvas drawer for example in class that needed it into the constructor. I kept thus all the from x import y to avoid having to do Folder.File.Class.Method and just do Class.Method.